# Is there a way to choose the scope of the generated code with Rust macros?

Tags: rust, macros, ffi

Suppose I have the following code:

```rust
struct Example;

impl Example {
    #[my_attr_macro]
    fn method() -> Self {
        Self;
    }
}
```

I want to generate a function that will eventually call this method in its body. I am able to generate such a function already but it's placed inside the `impl` block. Is there any way to generate on the outer scope of the `impl` block?

This outer function will be called from `C` code so it has use `C` ABI and it must have a specific name (which I will also generate) to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally no. But if all you want is to access it via FFI, then you can export it with this name to the C code by using `#[no_mangle]`:

```rust
impl Example {
    #[my_attr_macro]
    pub fn method() -> Self {
        #[no_mangle]
        extern "C" fn ffi_function() {}
    }
}
```

Now Rust code will not be able to call `ffi_function()`, but C code will be able to link against it (and of course Rust code too).

Comment: That's perfect, thanks! I didn't think `#[no_mangle]` would work for that case.